# 質問時に出てくるヘルプで、コードブロックの書き方を揃えたい

Tags: 討議

質問しようとしたとき右側のサイドバーに出てくる「文章の整え方」(How to Format) に、コードフェンスを使ったコードブロックの説明が追加されました。

しかしよく見ると、スペース4つ式の説明も載っており、チュートリアルとしてはむしろ分かりにくいのではないかと思っています。また、現状一番上に配置されていますが、もっと下に書くので良さそうです。

コードブロックに関する説明をもっと簡潔にできないでしょうか？

[image]

関連: [Minor concerns about the new question side-bar content](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/325719/341401)

Answer (score 8):

コードブロックに関しては「コードフェンス」か「スペース4つ」どちらか一方に絞り、詳しい情報は [文章の整え方についてのヘルプ](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help) にまかせればいいと思います。
(インデントのズレが起きにくい"コードフェンス"の方がおすすめ？この辺りはみんなの意見を見ながら)

合わせて、説明の並び順も書き手を意識したものに見直してもいいかもしれません。
「改行、段落、斜体・太字、コード」くらいの並び順で。